# Number of DFA states required

Tags: finite-automata

What is the minimal number of DFA states required to recognize binary numbers (encoded MSB to LSB) which are divisible by 6 and 8?

For divisibility by $6$ we required $6$ states.

For divisibility by $8$ we require $4$ states.

So in total, we need $6 \times 4$ states = $24$ states.

Am I correct? Can we do it with fewer states?

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal equivalent"? Is the binary number encoded MSB first or LSB first?

Comment: By decimal equivalent I mean that it's not the word length of binary string but the actual value like 1000 is 8 and not 4.

Comment: So this is MSB first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain an *upper bound* on the number of DFA states required to recognize some language, the simplest method is to give a DFA with that (or lower) number of states. In order to obtain a *lower bound* on the same number, the easiest route is to give $m$ pairwise indistinguishable words. These are $m$ words $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ such that for each $i \neq j$ there exists a word $y$ such that $x_i y \in L$ whereas $x_j y \notin L$, or vice versa. This set of words shows that every DFA for $L$ must contain at least $m$ states (why?).

In your case, the minimal number of states is much smaller than 24, though the exact number depends on the encoding. Instead of solving your question, let me calculate the minimal number of states in a DFA accepting all (non-empty) decimal numbers (encoded MSB to LSB) which are divisible by 6. I claim that this number is 4. For the upper bound, consider a DFA with states $q_0,q_1,q_2,q_A$, where $q_0$ is the initial state and $q_A$ is the accepting states. The transition table of the DFA is
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccc}
\delta & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
q_0 & q_A & q_1 & q_2 & q_0 & q_1 & q_2 & q_A & q_1 & q_2 & q_0 \\
q_1 & q_1 & q_2 & q_A & q_1 & q_2 & q_0 & q_1 & q_2 & q_A & q_1 \\
q_2 & q_2 & q_0 & q_1 & q_2 & q_A & q_1 & q_2 & q_0 & q_1 & q_2 \\
q_A & q_A & q_1 & q_2 & q_0 & q_1 & q_2 & q_A & q_1 & q_2 & q_0 \\
\end{array}
$$

You can show by induction that upon reading a word $w$:

- If $w = \epsilon$ or $w \equiv 3 \pmod{6}$, the machine is in state $q_0$.
- If $w \neq \epsilon$ and $w \equiv 1,4 \pmod{6}$, the machine is in state $q_1$.
- If $w \neq \epsilon$ and $w \equiv 2,5 \pmod{6}$, the machine is in state $q_2$.
- If $w \neq \epsilon$ and $w \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$, the machine is in state $q_A$.

This easily implies that this DFA accepts our language.

For the lower bounds, we use the set of words $\{0,1,2,3\}$. The following table gives the words $y$ separating each pair of words:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
y & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
0 & & \epsilon & \epsilon & \epsilon \\
1 & \epsilon & & 2 & 0 \\
2 & \epsilon & 2 & & 0 \\
3 & \epsilon & 0 & 0 &
\end{array}
$$
(These correspond to the states $q_A,q_1,q_2,q_0$.)

Comment: Sir, how are you considering input as 2,3,4,5 etc. It should be only 0's and 1's as it's binary right?

Comment: Let me quote myself: "Instead of solving your question, let me calculate the minimal number of states in a DFA accepting all (non-empty) decimal numbers (encoded MSB to LSB) which are divisible by 6."

Comment: I understood that your DFA accepts numbers divisible by 6 . But how did you construct it ? What do the states q0,q1,q2 mean ?

Comment: That's explained by the four bullets. They correspond to residues mod 6.

Comment: Till know I used to think that for all remainders we have separate states. Like for divisibility by 6, 6 states for remainders 0-5. How did you club remainder 1 and 4. Is it any divisibility trick?

Comment: Try proving by induction my description of the workings of the machine, and you will discover why it works.

Comment: Understood it. So what will be the answer to my original question ? Is it 4*4 = 16?

Comment: It's your question – you'll have to answer it.

Comment: I know that. But I want to know if just multiplying the states would work or not.

Comment: Probably not. Consider for example the case in which $6,8$ are replaced by $6,6$.

Comment: I just worked out few examples and found that the original problem would require 8 states. We need to check if last 4 bits are 0 and remaining bits are multiple of 3 or not. Am I correct?

Comment: I made no attempt to solve your actual question, but it can be solved using the method I outline. Perhaps you should try to *prove* that your answer is correct. This is how we know whether mathematical claims are valid or not.